# Changing collection in backbone marionette CompositeView

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, marionette

Actually I want to change my entire collection in an existing Marionette CompositeView without creating new object for that view.

I am not able to find method for this purpose I have read the documents [here](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.compositeview.md)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to do that by using the collection's reset method (http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-reset):

```
myView.collection.reset(models)
```

Where `myView` is your composite view instance, and `models` is an array of the models you want to have in the collection.

Comment: Hey man you are really rocking. This is exactly what I want. Thank you very much. +1 and I am accepting you answer.